# RxJs 5: Using filter error

Tags: angular, rxjs

Getting typescript error at `filter` pipe:

> `this` context of `void` is not assignable to method's `this` type of
>   `Observable<{}>`

**Code:**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { share } from "rxjs/operators/share";
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operator/filter';
import * as m from '../../models/app.models';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    observable: Observable<any>;
    observer: Observer<any>;

    constructor() {
        var temp = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.observer = observer;
        });
        this.observable = temp.share();
    }

    broadcast(event: m.SharedEventModel) {
        this.observer.next(event);
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        return this.observable.pipe(filter(x => x.Name === eventName)).subscribe(callback); <-- Error
    }
}
```

RxJs Version: 5.5.2

Comment: How do you import `filter`?

Comment: Updated the question with right code.

Comment: shouldn't it be `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';`?

Comment: That solved the issue, thanks a lot, was not able to figure this out at all!

Comment: If you want to use it in `pipe()` you need to import it from the `operators` directory like `import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators/filter';`